# Is it possible that a Peer AS over BGP can sniff other AS traffic?

Tags: sniffing, bgp

Is it possible that one AS can sniff another peer's traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad since you're not very explicit in which traffic you're talking about and what exactly the relationship between those two network is.

If two networks (ASNs) have a peering relationship and exchange routes, the result is that traffic is routed between those networks. Of course, network traffic from peer A which is routed to peer B can be sniffed by peer B (and vice versa), since it passes their network equipment.

Traffic exchanged between peer A and another peer C cannot be sniffed by peer B.

Comment: Thank you, as you said it traffic between two peer for example : A which is routed to point B, I used some site's like bgpview.io to get information about AS's and those peer's, if in some sites like bgpview display A as B peer it mean those are exchange route???

Comment: Depending on how that site gathers it's information (probably based on routing info in whois data), it sould mean that there's a peering relationship between two networks. That typically means that they exchange some routes.